# Use ressourceNames field in kubernetes RBAC that grants access to logs

Tags: kubernetes, security, logging, containers, rbac

I want to provide access to `logs` through a `ClusterRole` as follows

```yaml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: logs-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

Is there a way to limit this to a specific set of pod names? AFAIK the `resourceNames` field does not support wildcards, but on the other hand the pod names are not predictable so that I add something to the specific field

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to limit this to a specific set of pod names?

This ask hasn't evolved as a Kubernetes feature. Still, the conversations are going on the Kubernetes GitHub issue page.

Reference:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/56582
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44703